# How to use ASP .NET dropdown with ajax

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

Greeting,

I'm beginer of ajax technology and now i need to create two dropdown in 
MVC project for example:

First dropdown has the list of classroom `[601,602,603]` when i choose one then next 
dropdown will has the list of student belong to each class room.

Now, I already create the repository class that has method `GetStudentByClassroomName()`
and already connect to the database.

Can anyone give me a suggestion how to create it or any technology to create the dropdown like this?

Thank you very much ^_^

Answer (score 1):

Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/746815/how-to-get-the-json-object-for-drop-down/748446#748446) - similar problem (cascading drop down)

Answer (score 0):

check the CascadingDropDown from the ajaxcontroltoolkit.

http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/Samples/CascadingDropDown/CascadingDropDown.aspx